# Issue with dynamically added android radiobutton

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

I have an android app which asks a question followed by x number of options. Each option contains a textview, ImageView and a radio button.

The value of x (i.e. the number of options) is not constant. I want to dynamically add UI content to satisfy this requirement.

This I am doing using the following code

```
LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout linearLayoutThis = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lladrList);


    for (int i =0 ;i< options.length; i++){
        LinearLayout lladroption=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.adroption, null);
         //get view id and set values
         ImageView iv = (ImageView) lladroption.findViewById(R.id.ivadroption);
         iv.setId(OPTIONIMAGE+i);
         iv.setImageBitmap(downloadFile(options[i].getOptionData().getDataURL()));
         ((ViewGroup) iv.getParent()).removeView(iv);
         iv.setOnClickListener(this);
         linearLayoutThis.addView(iv);
         RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) lladroption.findViewById(R.id.rbadroption);

         rb.setOnClickListener(this);
         rb.setId(OPTIONRADIOBUTTON+i);
         rb.setText(options[i].getOptionString());
         ((ViewGroup) rb.getParent()).removeView(rb);
         linearLayoutThis.addView(rb);
        // rg.addView(rb);
    }
```

I want the radiobuttons to belong to a particular radiogroup. But if I do a 
rg.addView(rb) instead of linearLayoutThis.addView(rb); in the above code where rg is the radiogroup view ... all the radiobuttons are display in one go. Instead of displaying text,image,radiobutton,text,image,radiobutton,text,image,radiobutton I get text,image,text,image,text,image,radiobutton,radiobutton,radiobutton. 
Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to add those dynamically. create a view group or layout with the textview image and the radio button you require. use listview to get the x number of options. If this is your requirment you can reply so that i can help you with it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Rakshi. The requirement is that I get the list of options from a server. Based on the list which contains an array of options and each option has a text and image url. Also at the bottom of the screen there is to be a submit button.